# Top User SQL Query With Categories?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to get the top users in each category with a mysql query:
My Users Table looks like this:

user_id,category_id ... and some other stuff

My Votes Table looks like this (each row is one positive vote):
reciever_id ... and some other stuff

I was thinking that I need to first determine the unique votes by user_id like this:

```
reciever_id, votes
1 2
2 6
```

Then I could order that by the number of votes ...
Then select the users.whatever,distinct(category_id) from users, (that query) WHERE users_id=that_queries_user.id

Anyways I'm probably obviously really confused as to how to write this query and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return you top 10 users:

```
SELECT  u.*,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    votes v
        WHERE   v.receiver_id = u.user_id
        ) AS score
FROM    users u
ORDER BY
        score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This will return you one top user from each category:

```
SELECT  u.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT category_id
        FROM    users
        ) uo
JOIN    users u
ON      u.user_id = 
        (
        SELECT  user_id
        FROM    users ui
        WHERE   ui.category_id = uo.category_id
        ORDER BY
                (
                SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    votes v
                WHERE   v.receiver_id = ui.user_id
                ) DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Comment: This bottom one is the closest but does not return unique user ids and category ids ...

Comment: @Travis: it returns everything from the user table, including user id's and category id's. If you want only these, replace `u.*` with the fields you want.

Comment: @Travis: Could you please post some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

try this (if, as you say, each row is one positive vote):

```
  Select User_id, category_id, Count(*) voteCnt
  From Users u Join Votes v 
     On v.receiver_id = u.user_id
  Group By User_id, category_id
  Having Count(*) > [Whayever Threshold you want]
  Order By Count(*) Desc
```

or this if the votes column is actually the count of votes:

```
  Select User_id, category_id, Sum(votes) voteSum
  From Users u Join Votes v 
     On v.receiver_id = u.user_id
  Group By User_id, category_id
  Having Sum(votes) > [Whayever Threshold you want]
  Order By Sum(votes) Desc
```